# 2 minute ssh timeout. How to increase?

Tags: ssh

I'm trying to do a mysqldump via ssh, using a command like this...

```
ssh -o "BatchMode yes" my-ssh-host "mysqldump ..."
```

The issue I'm encountering is that the connection is timing out if mysqldump takes longer than 2 minutes. I can't seem to increase this.

I've attempted to fix it by doing this...

On the server, /etc/ssh/sshd_config, I've added the following...

```
TCPKeepAlive yes
ClientAliveInterval 15
ClientAliveCountMax 100
```

On the client in ~/.ssh/config, I've added the following...

```
Host my-ssh-host
  ...
  TcpKeepAlive yes
  ServerAliveInterval 15
  ServerAliveTimeout 100
```

Neither of these things has made any difference. The connection still times out after approximately 2m9s.

The mysqldump will need at least 10 minutes to reliably complete. How can I ensure that ssh will stay connected long enough?

Comment: Try running the command with the `-v -v -v` switches. If the keepalive is working, you should see messages `send packet: type 80` and `receive packet: type 82` popping up periodically. Also, do you happen to have a firewall between the two computers?

Comment: I've just noticed something which may be relevant. The timeout only seems to occur when I'm running the ssh command from a script. If I run it directly in my terminal, it works. Would there be something I need to set in my script to allow the ssh to run for longer without timing out?

Comment: I'm trying it now with the -v -v -v. I can see the send/receive packet notifications.

Comment: Oddly enough after enabling the -v options, the timeout is not occuring. I'm not sure if this is related or not, or if the issue is slightly random.

Comment: Try restarting the service. On the server: systemctl restart sshd

Answer (score 0):

My SSH disconnected after about two minutes, if I did not press any keys.
I used `tmux` after login by SSH and my problem solved.

see a example document for `tmux` [here](https://linuxize.com/post/getting-started-with-tmux/).